Difference between でしょう, でしょうね and でしょうか
I have recently learned about the usage of でしょう with an ascending intonation (as opposed to the descending tone of conjectures) to ask for confirmation.

3月にタイへ旅行したでしょう。(rising intonation) = You travelled to Thailand in March, didn't you?

Typically, when I learn about a new grammatical structure, I learn it in the affirmative form and then with the usual meaning of the particles か and I can form questions ね (with the latter "right?/isn't it?" questions). In the case of でしょう it appears to be more complicated, because it seems to already carry the meaning of ね, so what is でしょうね? I could guess that it just strengthens the "right?/isn't it?", but it gets even more difficult when I find でしょうか. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a lot on grammar books about でしょうか, just a line on the 12th lecture of the first volume of Genki. As I said, I wouldn't normally ask this, but since でしょう。(rising intonation) already seems to carry a question, I'm troubled.
I could guess this is a softer way of asking something? Here is an example sentence I have found:

東京までどのくらいかかるでしょうか。

How is it different from the following sentence?

東京までどのくらいかかるですか。


This isn't really a matter of "grammatical structure". でしょう is simply the volitional of です, but it has idiomatic uses that don't directly follow from the grammar rules.
In effect:
です -> neutrally making a claim of fact
ですか -> neutrally asking whether something is the case (you don't know if it's true or not)
ですね -> seeking agreement regarding the claim
でしょう -> expressing belief in a proposition, rather than knowledge of a fact
でしょうか -> asking, but with the implication of anticipating a positive answer (you surmise that something is true and seek verification)
でしょうね -> implicitly "asking", but with the implication of socially expecting a positive answer
And yes, it's more nuanced than that. か doesn't directly mark a question, after all - it can be used mid-sentence and in constructions like なにか/なんか, and isn't necessary when intonation does the trick. And on the other hand か could be used explicitly on what is intended as a rhetorical question (possibly stated with falling intonation). You're expected to read the air.

You say that "でしょうか -> asking, but with the implication of anticipating a positive answer (you surmise that something is true and seek verification)", but my example (taken from a book) looks a little different. The person asking wants to know how long it takes to go to Tokyo. What would a positive answer be?
Also, regarding "でしょう -> expressing belief in a proposition, rather than knowledge of a fact", it seems that you are talking about making conjectures. The one I'm talking about is the rising intonation (often denoted in books as ↗) to seek confirmation.
